# Scala List mapping to another list with next and previous value

Tags: scala, list, mapping

How do I map a Scala list to a new List based on the previous value?
For example, I would like to map `List(40,70,30)` into `List(40, 110, 100)`

Answer (score 2):

Use [List.sliding](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html?search=rich#sliding(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]) to create (sliding window) blocks of two elements

```
val lst = List(40,70,30)
lst.head +: lst.sliding(2).map(_.sum).toList
```